# Proper way to prevent Doctrine record from being deleted

Tags: php, doctrine, record

Can I just override `delete()` method of `Doctrine_Record`?

```
class myRec extends myRecBase
  public function delete() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Or use `preDelete` hook? Or throw an exception in `delete()`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use the preDelete method to simply skip the delete method all together.

Example:

```
public function preDelete(Doctrine_Event $event)
{
   $event->skipOperation();
}
```

You should be able to do this within your extended Doctrine_Record classes or, as an alternative, with a listener.  A listener may be beneficial in the cases where you want some part of your application to have the ability to delete records (e.g. an admin section vs client side code).

With the listener approach you create a listener with the above preDelete method and register it with your Table like this:

```
$userTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User');
$userTable->addRecordListener(new HydrationListener());
```

If the listener is not registered you will still be able to delete records.  If the listener is registered your deletes will not persist to the database.

More information about that method can be found here:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/event-listeners/en

Answer (score -1):

IMHO I would probably do it that way too as a preDelete hook is still going to execute the delete method afterwards.